# Windows Workgoup - is there a way to centrally install a software?

Tags: windows, automated-install, workgroup

I have a client server application - intended for use in workgoups.

The server is a web application, clients are .NET 2.0 based desktop applications.

Is there a way to push/force the setup of the client application on all machines in the network?

Any group policy equivalent/any way to centrally manage/push an installation on a windows workgroup based network?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not built in, that's very much the point of Active Directory.

You need an account on each machine which is a member of the Local Administrators group and has a known password, (if you spend the time setting this up once it could be useful later). With that list of usernames and passwords you could script remote installations using Sysinternals' **PSEXEC** for example.

There are also third party solutions where an agent is installed on each machine, like Microsoft's SMS (now **System Center Configuration Manager**) or the free and open source **OCS Inventory NG**.

Answer (score 3):

You could still run a local login script on each pc, that connects to a "master" pc with the software on it and installs it from there. Checkout gpedit.msc and go to **User Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Scripts (Logon/Logoff)**. Edit the Logon item and point to your script (batch file would be ok). The user would need admin rights locally and rights on the master pc.

Comment: Probably as good as anything is going to do w/out Active Directory.